# Android - Issue with AutoCompleteTextView element, setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I have the following Activity code which ref. the R.layout.pool_details_new_layout (code below)

The Adapter ref. the number_of_players_dropdown_layout (code below)

Everything works fine, the view loads the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown box populates and when i click on it is shows all the entires in it

BUT

when i select an item, I am expecting for the `numPlayersSelected.setOnItemClickListener` to execute and log to the logcat and show a toast on the screen but nothing happens!?

Does anyone know what i am missing!?

### Activity code:

```
public class PoolDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<SkuItem> numPlayersAdapter;
    private AutoCompleteTextView numPlayersSelected;
    public static Activity activity = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        setContentView(R.layout.pool_details_new_layout);
       
        activity = this;

        numPlayersSelected = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.numOfPlayersAddSelected);
                    
        numPlayersAdapter = new IAPSkuAdapter(activity, R.layout.number_of_players_dropdown_layout, numPlayersArray);

        numPlayersSelected.setAdapter(numPlayersAdapter);

        // NOT WORKING!?   <-------------------------------------
        numPlayersSelected.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),selectedItemText + " selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "<< SELECTED >> : " + selectedItemText);

            }

        }
                    
    }

}
```

### number_of_players_dropdown_layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adminLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Add Players"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#605E5E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/numPlayersDropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:hint="Select"
                android:labelFor="@+id/numOfPlayersSelected"
                android:background="#EAE7E7">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/numOfPlayersAddSelected"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

### pool_details_new_layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".PoolDetailsActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/admin_support_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/pool_details_admin_layout" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

-------------- UPDATE ----------------

### Adapter Class Code:

```
public class IAPSkuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SkuItem> {

    public IAPSkuAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<SkuItem> skuItemList) {
  
        super(context, resource, skuItemList);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.number_of_players_dropdown_layout, parent, false);

        }

        TextView skuTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.skuTitle);

        TextView skuPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.skuPrice);

        SkuItem skuItem = getItem(position);

        skuTitle.setText(skuItem.getSkuTitle());
    
        skuPrice.setText(skuItem.getSkuPrice());
    

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things you could try:

1. You could try to setup the `clickListener()` Method in the Adapter for each item:

`convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> { //Your code here });`
In this example we assume that the click method should be triggerd when the `convertView` is pressed.

2. Also try to make sure that the array `numPlayersArray` isn't empty, when the ClickListener gets assigned.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: can you provide sample code for the first option? I am new to android programming coming from ios.

Comment: I have added my current Adapter code

Comment: I've added some sample code. Please let me know if it works or if you're facing any issues.

Comment: So i did that, but now the behaviour of the dropdown menu is not working. I put a basic `Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Sku Selected: " + sku.getSkuTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` which displays correctly and all but the menu does NOT close like you would expect it to once a user selects an item!?

Comment: For that you need to hide the parent view by changing its visibility. In that case I belive it works like this: `parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. But I'm  not sure if this is working in your case. If not, you probably have to access the parent view by getting the parent through:  `convertView.getParent()` and then changing the visibility. Or you can pass it from outside into the adapter.